# Unable to fix an interface implementation error

Tags: c#

This is the error message I am getting:

> 'BusinessLogicLayer' does not implement interface member 'IBusinessLogicLayer.ColorSource_GetByID(Guid)'. 'BusinessLogicLayer.ColorSource_GetByID(Guid)' cannot implement 'IBusinessLogicLayer.ColorSource_GetByID(Guid)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'ColorIndex'.

My code for the specific region in the BLL causing the error is:

```
namespace TartanGenerator.BLL
{
    public interface IBusinessLogicLayer
    {
        ColorIndex ColorSource_GetByID(Guid ColorSourceID);
    }

    public class BusinessLogicLayer : IBusinessLogicLayer
    {
        private readonly IColorSourceRepository _IColorSourceRepository;

        public BusinessLogicLayer()
        {
            _IColorSourceRepository = new ColorSourceRepository();
        }

        public BusinessLogicLayer(IColorSourceRepository ColorSourceRepository)
        {
            _IColorSourceRepository = ColorSourceRepository;
        }

        public ColorSource ColorSource_GetByID(Guid ColorSourceID)
        {
// This is where I believe the error is coming from 
            return _IColorSourceRepository.GetSingle(cs => cs.RecordID.Equals(ColorSourceID));
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know what other source code to supply to be helpfull, this is the first time I've attempted this way of doing EF.

**EDIT 1**

I have searched my entire solution and the only place where the two types are even in the same method is the EDMX file. otherwise the two never meet.

Comment: interface - `ColorIndex ColorSource_GetByID`, realization - `ColorSource ColorSource_GetByID`. `ColorIndex` != `ColorSource`

Comment: Your method signatures don't match, specifically the return types.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with Windows Fomrs or Entity Framework. It's very clear actually - a method has the wrong signature

Comment: Could the error message be any more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Change your function like this:

```
            ColorIndex ColorSource_GetByID(Guid ColorSourceID)
            {
                // This is where I believe the error is coming from 
                return _IColorSourceRepository.GetSingle(cs => cs.RecordID.Equals(ColorSourceID));
            }
```

While implementing an interface in a class right click on the interface name in visual studio and you will see an option named implement interface. This will create the interface implementation without signature mismatch for you.

```
 public class BusinessLogicLayer : IBusinessLogicLayer
```

Right click on IBusinessLogicLayer to get that option.

Comment: Tried that and it keeps placing the wrong type. I may need to slash and burn in order to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your existing method has an incorrect return-type to match the interface method. Since the return types are not part of method signatures, you cannot add another method which only differs in the return type.

What you can do, is implement the interface method explicitly.

```
ColorIndex IBusinessLogicLayer.ColorSource_GetByID(Guid ColorSourceID) {
    var colorSource = ColorSource_GetByID(ColorSourceID);
    var colorIndex = // Do something to convert a color-source to a color-index.
    return colorIndex;
}
```